# How to convert Public key (hex) to SS58 Address in JavaScript / Polkadot-JS?

Tags: polkadot-js, hash

I have a Public key (hex) and would like to convert it to an SS58 Address. What is the right function to use?

I found the docs here with an code-sniped: https://substrate-developer-hub.github.io/docs/en/knowledgebase/advanced/ss58-address-format

Public key (hex):         0x46ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a

SS58 Address: 12bzRJfh7arnnfPPUZHeJUaE62QLEwhK48QnH9LXeK2m1iZU

```
// Import Polkadot.js API dependencies.
const { decodeAddress, encodeAddress } = require("@polkadot/keyring");
const { hexToU8a, isHex } = require("@polkadot/util");

isHex(address)
hexToU8a(address)
decodeAddress(address)
encodeAddress(address)
```

But these functions do not bring the right results..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

All you need is to add prefix when using `encodeAddress(address, prefix)`, as in the wiki for the Polkadot-js API (https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/ss58/)

A snippet:

```
const { encodeAddress } = require("@polkadot/keyring");

const address = "0x46ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a";

console.log(encodeAddress(address, 0)); //"12bzRJfh7arnnfPPUZHeJUaE62QLEwhK48QnH9LXeK2m1iZU"
```

Note: prefix `0` is for Polkadot address

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `subkey inspect`:

```
subkey inspect --keystore-uri 0x46ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a --network polkadot
URI: 
Secret Key URI `` is account:
  Secret seed:       0xfac7959dbfe72f052e5a0c3c8d6530f202b02fd8f9f5ca3580ec8deb7797479e
  Public key (hex):  0x46ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a
  Public key (SS58): 12bzRJfh7arnnfPPUZHeJUaE62QLEwhK48QnH9LXeK2m1iZU
  Account ID:        0x46ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a
  SS58 Address:      12bzRJfh7arnnfPPUZHeJUaE62QLEwhK48QnH9LXeK2m1iZU
```

Answer (score 1):

subscan provide convert tool [here](https://kusama.subscan.io/tools/format_transform)