# Get SS58 Address from public key

Tags: rust, address

I have my hex public key, how can I convert it to an SS58 Address?

I have found the snippet to do it using PolkadotJS here: [How to convert Public key (hex) to SS58 Address in JavaScript / Polkadot-JS?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/787/how-to-convert-public-key-hex-to-ss58-address-in-javascript-polkadot-js) simply using `const { encodeAddress } = require("@polkadot/keyring");`

Is there a similar way to do that in Rust?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert HEX public key into SS58](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2367/how-to-convert-hex-public-key-into-ss58)

Comment: No, this answer is using tools subkey and subalfred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is an easy way to do it like it is with PolkadotJS, but I check the code of the `subkey tool` and can share how I am getting a SS58 Address from a hex public key.

```rs
use sp_core::{crypto::{Ss58AddressFormatRegistry, Ss58Codec}, sr25519::Pair};
use sp_runtime::{MultiSigner};

let ss58_address = hex_public_key_to_ss58_address::<Pair>(public_str)?;

fn hex_public_key_to_ss58_address<Pair>(
    public_str: String,
) -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
where
    Pair: sp_core::Pair,
    Pair::Public: Into<MultiSigner>,
{
    let public = array_bytes::hex2bytes(&public_str).expect("Failed to convert hex to bytes");
    let public_key = Pair::Public::try_from(&public)
        .map_err(|_| "Failed to construct public key from given hex")?;
    let ss58_address = public_key.to_ss58check_with_version(Ss58AddressFormatRegistry::SubstrateAccount.into()):

    Ok(ss58_address)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a similar way to do that in Rust. You can use the `sp_core` crate. Here is an example of how to convert a hex public key to an SS58 address in Rust:

you can use the `sp_core` crate, which is part of the Substrate framework, to perform this conversion in Rust. Here's an example of how to achieve it:

```rust
extern crate sp_core;

use sp_core::crypto::Ss58Codec;

fn main() {
    let hex_public_key = "46ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a";
    let public_key = hex::decode(hex_public_key).expect("Failed to decode hex public key");
    let ss58_address = sp_core::crypto::AccountId32::from(public_key.as_slice()).to_ss58check();

    println!("SS58 address: {}", ss58_address);
}
```

Ensure you have the `sp-core` crate added as a dependency in your `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[dependencies]
sp-core = "2.0"
```

In this example, we decode the hex public key using `hex::decode` assuming you have the `hex` crate as a dependency as well. Then, we create an `AccountId32` instance using `sp_core::crypto::AccountId32::from` by passing the decoded public key as a slice.

Finally, we use the `to_ss58check` method on the `AccountId32` instance to obtain the SS58 address representation.

Comment: Following this instructions I get an error importing {encode, AddressFormat}

Comment: can you please follow the above , sorry for my previos response

Comment: Thanks! that snippet still gives me an error: the trait `From<&[u8]>` is not implemented for `sp_core::crypto::AccountId32`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [tool](https://snow-address-converter.netlify.app/) to get ss58 from your Public key(Hex) you may also check [this](https://polkadot.subscan.io/tools/format_transform?input=0xa45dfaccf0fca1062703dda957076c26cf5c6feb11d8240b6d646916a8c05277&type=All)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for a tool, I am looking for a code snippet